# Symfony. Use form to add rows to doctrine database.

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Well i need to add rows to data table in doctrine. Of course i know how to create database and how to add some data without form. But i need to make symfony made page to add rows to databasy via created form.

This is route for form builder

```
    /**
 * @route("/lol")
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    // createFormBuilder is a shortcut to get the "form factory"
    // and then call "createBuilder()" on it

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('Pytanie', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('Odpowiedz1', TextType::class)
        ->add('Prawidlowa1', CheckboxType::class)
        ->add('Odpowiedz2', TextType::class)
        ->add('Prawidlowa2', CheckboxType::class)
        ->add('Odpowiedz3', TextType::class)
        ->add('Prawidlowa3', CheckboxType::class)
        ->add('Odpowiedz4', TextType::class)
        ->add('Prawidlowa4', CheckboxType::class)
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('quiz/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

This is what is in twig file

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

<input type="submit" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

And of course created entity.

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * pytanie
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pytanie")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\pytanieRepository")
 */
class pytanie
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Pytanie", type="text")
     */
    private $pytanie;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="odpowiedz1", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $odpowiedz1;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prawidlowa1", type="boolean", nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $prawidlowa1;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pytanie2", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $pytanie2;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prawidlowa2", type="boolean", nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $prawidlowa2;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="odpowiedz3", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $odpowiedz3;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prawidlowa3", type="boolean", nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $prawidlowa3;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="odpowiedz4", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $odpowiedz4;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prawidlowa4", type="boolean", nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $prawidlowa4;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set pytanie
     *
     * @param string $pytanie
     *
     * @return pytanie
     */
    public function setPytanie($pytanie)
    {
        $this->pytanie = $pytanie;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pytanie
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPytanie()
    {
        return $this->pytanie;
    }

    /**
     * Set odpowiedz1
     *
     * @param string $odpowiedz1
     *
     * @return pytanie
     */
    public function setOdpowiedz1($odpowiedz1)
    {
        $this->odpowiedz1 = $odpowiedz1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get odpowiedz1
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOdpowiedz1()
    {
        return $this->odpowiedz1;
    }

    /**
     * Set prawidlowa1
     *
     * @param boolean $prawidlowa1
     *
     * @return pytanie
     */
    public function setPrawidlowa1($prawidlowa1)
    {
        $this->prawidlowa1 = $prawidlowa1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get prawidlowa1
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getPrawidlowa1()
    {
        return $this->prawidlowa1;
    }

    /**
     * Set pytanie2
     *
     * @param string $pytanie2
     *
     * @return pytanie
     */
    public function setPytanie2($pytanie2)
    {
        $this->pytanie2 = $pytanie2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pytanie2
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPytanie2()
    {
        return $this->pytanie2;
    }

    /**
     * Set prawidlowa2
     *
     * @param boolean $prawidlowa2
     *
     * @return pytanie
     */
    public function setPrawidlowa2($prawidlowa2)
    {
        $this->prawidlowa2 = $prawidlowa2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get prawidlowa2
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getPrawidlowa2()
    {
        return $this->prawidlowa2;
    }

    /**
     * Set odpowiedz3
     *
     * @param string $odpowiedz3
     *
     * @return pytanie
     */
    public function setOdpowiedz3($odpowiedz3)
    {
        $this->odpowiedz3 = $odpowiedz3;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get odpowiedz3
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOdpowiedz3()
    {
        return $this->odpowiedz3;
    }

    /**
     * Set prawidlowa3
     *
     * @param boolean $prawidlowa3
     *
     * @return pytanie
     */
    public function setPrawidlowa3($prawidlowa3)
    {
        $this->prawidlowa3 = $prawidlowa3;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get prawidlowa3
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getPrawidlowa3()
    {
        return $this->prawidlowa3;
    }

    /**
     * Set odpowiedz4
     *
     * @param string $odpowiedz4
     *
     * @return pytanie
     */
    public function setOdpowiedz4($odpowiedz4)
    {
        $this->odpowiedz4 = $odpowiedz4;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get odpowiedz4
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOdpowiedz4()
    {
        return $this->odpowiedz4;
    }

    /**
     * Set prawidlowa4
     *
     * @param boolean $prawidlowa4
     *
     * @return pytanie
     */
    public function setPrawidlowa4($prawidlowa4)
    {
        $this->prawidlowa4 = $prawidlowa4;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get prawidlowa4
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getPrawidlowa4()
    {
        return $this->prawidlowa4;
    }
}
```

I created this so far. but then i'm stuck. And i cant find any good hint to make this form write data to database.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle form submission like this :

```
/**
 * @route("/lol")
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{

    // first create new empty object
    $pytanie = new pitanie();

     // then you create your form with your object
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($pitanie)
        ->add('Pytanie', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('Odpowiedz1', TextType::class)
        ->add('Prawidlowa1', CheckboxType::class)
        ->add('Odpowiedz2', TextType::class)
        ->add('Prawidlowa2', CheckboxType::class)
        ->add('Odpowiedz3', TextType::class)
        ->add('Prawidlowa3', CheckboxType::class)
        ->add('Odpowiedz4', TextType::class)
        ->add('Prawidlowa4', CheckboxType::class)
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
         // $form->getData() holds the submitted values
         // but, the original `$pitanie` variable has also been updated
        $pitanie = $form->getData();
         // ... perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
         // for example, if Task is a Doctrine entity, save it!
         // $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         // $em->persist($task);
         // $em->flush();

         return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
    }
    return $this->render('quiz/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Check the doc for more info : 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions